# Success message is not showing while submit review form in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-review, success-message

I am facing issue when submit review form in product detail page.when submit review then success message is not showing after reload.

But when adding product to cart on the same page then it showing correctly. When I move to another page then whole messages at time like below image:

[image]

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue ?

Comment: yes i have posted answer below

Comment: Can you please, let me know in detail in which Js file I have do this changes. As such I have tried it but still not getting any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolve isssue from below referance link:
[here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Error-Success-message-not-showing-on-one-page-in-custom-module/td-p/72823)

I was using

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
```

for the javascript validation.

I changed it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```